# How to know when composer install finishes in docker container

Tags: php, jenkins, docker, composer-php

I am using docker to deploy java and php components.

From jenkins I run something like `docker run --name my_php_component -d -t my_php_image`.

Inside of the container `deploy.sh` script will be executed. This script runs `composer install`.

Jenkins needs to know that/when this has finished successfully and then it can run end-to-end tests.

What is the best way for it to check that `composer install` has successfully installed all packages inside the docker container?

Comment: Don't run Composer inside the container. Run it outside, and then provide the installed files INTO that container. I believe Docker is built that way: You have a controlled runtime environment inside, and the necessary files are provided from outside. Plenty of articles all deal with how it is not necessary to actually have a shell into the container, or write logfiles, or have anything development-related like a build toolchain, so this makes me think you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Sven I will look more into the approach that you mentioned.